# Listing or stacking nodes on top of each other in forest

Tags: forest

I'm wanting to make a logic tree using forest that looks something like the picture below:
[image]

I'm struggling to list the premises of the argument at the first node of the tree in the way that is done in the picture. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show your best effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, please provide a [Minimal (non-)Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

```
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
  \forestset{
    close me/.style={label={below:\textasteriskcentered}},
  }
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      align=center,
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south,
      where level=0{}{math content},
    }
    [$(P \land R)$\\$\lnot(P \land Q)$\\$\lnot\lnot(R \lor Q)$\\$P$\\$R$\\$(R \lor Q)$
      [\lnot P, close me]
      [\lnot Q
        [R]
        [Q, close me]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree proof]

Comment: `prooftrees` would do it better, of course ...